# An exercise about sets of Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $A \subseteq [a,b]$. Then $\mu^*(A)=0$ if and only if exists a sequence of open intervals $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that covers $A$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(I_n) < \infty$ and every $x \in A$ belongs to an infinite number of $I_n$'s.

$\mu^*$ denotes the Lebesgue outer measure.

Can someone give me a proof or a help for this statement?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes but i did not come up with any sollution

Comment: *What* have you tried, not *did* you try.

Comment: from the definition of the outer measure in R i took an open cover of open intervals such that the sum of their length <$\epsilon$ .but i cannot find a way to prove that every element in A belongs to an infinite number of In's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Points of a Measure Zero Sets Covered by Intervals Infinitely Many Times](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226293/points-of-a-measure-zero-sets-covered-by-intervals-infinitely-many-times)

Comment: @aduh The forward direction here is a duplicate of that, but the other direction is not.